# Creating a Resharper Naming Style for C# Contract Classes

Tags: c#, resharper, code-contracts

When writing code contracts on interfaces using Microsoft's Code Contracts, one creates an abstract contract class that contains all the contracts:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

[ContractClass(typeof(ICollectionContract<>))]
public interface ICollection<T> {
    // Interface methods
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(ICollection<>))]
abstract class ICollectionContract<T> : ICollection<T> {
    // Interface contracts
}
```

The Microsoft convention is to name the contract class the same as the interface, but with a suffix of `Contract`, e.g. `ICollectionContract<T>`.
However, Resharper is not a fan of the naming - partly due to the `I` prefix for an abstract class.

Is there a way to create a naming style that tells Resharper that contract classes (those annotated with `ContractClassFor`) must have the same name as the interface but with a suffix of `Contract`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not something you can configure ReSharper to do out of the box, you'd have to create a custom plugin.

You'd have to create an `ElementProblemAnalyzer<IInterfaceDeclaration>`, then check that it contains the `[ContractClass]` attribute, and then make sure it has the correct name. You can also create a QuickFix suggestion to rename the interface.

A good start would be something similar to the [AsyncSuffix plugin](https://github.com/asizikov/AsyncSuffix) - it has a good implementation that analyzes async methods for a missing `Async` suffix, offering to add it. Look at that implementation for ideas for your own plugin.